# magento 2 Warning: the image cannot be removed as it has been assigned to the other image role

Tags: php, magento, magento2

**Steps to reproduce**

Edit a Product

Delete an image not assigned to a role

**Expected result**

Image to be deleted

**Actual result**

Image not deleted

Error displayed: The image cannot be removed as it has been assigned to the other image role

How can I delete the product image ?

Comment: Please ask a question.

Comment: How can delete the image for a product (ie Grouped or Configurable  ) if the above error throws while deleting image ?Can you guide to rectify this issue ?

Comment: reference here for the cause:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/169564/magento-2-the-image-cannot-be-removed-as-it-has-been-assigned-to-the-other-image?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because you try to delete an image which has at least one role (Base, Small, Thumbnail or Swatch) defined on one of your scope.
Remove all the roles and you will be able to delete the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can change product image attributes (thumbnail,image, swatch_image, base_image) scope from store view to Global if you want same images on all store views. By doing this you will be able to change image from any store view and images will be same on all other store views.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I was having the same issue.

LawCha & Ali's answer's are both correct.

If you're intention is for each store view to always show the same images and roles, go to Stores > Attributes and change each of the 4 image roles to Global.